# Which way to merge with git?

Tags: git, merge, branch

Say I have two branches

```
master -- A -   -   -   -   -  - merge
          \                    /
           \- develop -- B -- C
```

Now if I want to merge it will be a fast forward, but should I do

```
git checkout develop
git merge master
```

or

```
git checkout master
git merge develop
```

And what if I have possible conflicts

```
master -- A - D -  -  -  -  -  -merge
          \                   /
           \- develop -- B -- C
```

Should I now merge in to develop or into master? This is a bit confusing, so a good explanation would be really appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to do something that's based on [this branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)?

Comment: Yes, I think so at least :P New at both git and version control you see

Comment: If you are trying to follow that model, you should never have a situation like the one you described where commit D is in *master* but not in *develop*.  All of your work would go into *develop* and hot fixes would be merged into both *master* and *develop*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Missing Workflow Tasks

First of all, there are a few things missing in your workflow that make it hard to answer your question in a real-world way. For example:

1. You should always pull from upstream before merging branches. Others may have changed *develop* or *master* in ways that you haven't accounted for.
2. You haven't identified which is your long-lived line of development. One assumes *develop*, but that's just a guess because you haven't identified what happens to your branches *after* the merge.

#### General Best Practices for Rebasing Long-Lived Branches

So, assuming that you've updated your branches ahead of time, and that *master* and *develop* are both long-lived branches and that *master* is the "official" branch for completed code, then you should do something along these lines.

1. Make a temporary rebasing branch based on *develop*.

   ```
   git checkout -b tmp develop
   ```
2. Rebase your work onto *master* to ensure a clean fast-forward merge. I like to make this an interactive rebase, but do it any way you want. For example:

   ```
   git rebase -i master
   ```
3. Merge onto *master*. I prefer to force the merge to be a fast-forward, but you can do whatever suits you.

   ```
   git checkout master
   git merge --ff-only tmp
   ```
4. Make sure the merged branch pushes cleanly.

   ```
   git push origin
   ```
5. If all went well, dispose of your temporary branch.

   ```
   git branch -d tmp
   ```
6. Re-merge *master* with *develop* as a merge commit, rather than a fast-forward. This brings your development into line with the master branch for continued work.

   ```
   git checkout develop
   git merge master
   git push origin
   ```

#### Natural Consequences

Doing this ensures that the history on your *master* branch is relatively linear and free from merge conflicts, and still allows you to rebase when needed without screwing up published branches. This is all positive stuff.

However, this process can leave *develop* with a complex merge history since the re-merging from *master* to *develop* may not always be a fast-forward merge. This isn't a problem, per se, it's just a natural consequence of any workflow that includes rebasing. It's something to be aware of, but in my opinion it's a price worth paying for the flexibility it offers the team.

Answer (score 3):

do the second, merge while in master.

I typically rebase master to origin, the rebase dev to master, *then* merge.  This makes the conflicts appear during the rebase; if you do this, there will be no merge conflicts.

Comment: At gitimmersion I read that rebasing was not good practice when working on public repos, because it may be confusing for other users. Do I avoid that using your routine?

Comment: http://gitimmersion.com/lab_34.html : Don’t use rebase …

If the branch is public and shared with others. Rewriting publicly shared branches will tend to screw up other members of the team.
 When the exact history of the commit branch is important (since rebase rewrites the commit history).
Given the above guidelines, I tend to use rebase for short-lived, local branches and merge for branches in the public repository.

Comment: right, its ok to rebase your dev branch, you would never rebase your master branch

Comment: For completeness, note that your first option would really be a no-op, since you would check out `dev` (commit 'C' in your diagram), then merging `master` (commit 'A') would see that 'A' is already in the history of the `dev` branch, so there's nothing to do. If there were additional commits on `master` after 'A', though, that would be different, but then your second option wouldn't be a fast-forward, either...